# sorting a 2d string array by alphabetizing in c

Tags: c, sorting, multidimensional-array, c-strings

my loop is only arranging the first element, i tried putting an outer loop but it is not working. do i need another loop within my program or initialize another char array[] to transfer the loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char applicants[10][15],temp[15];
    char swap[10][15];
    int apps,i,j,c=0;

    printf("how many applicants?\n");
    scanf("%d",&apps);

    printf("enter the names of the applicants on seperate lines\n");
    printf("in order in which they applied for > ");
    for (i=0;i<apps;i++){
       scanf("%s",applicants[i]);
    }

    printf("\napplication order\n");
    printf("-----------------\n");
    for (i=0;i<apps;i++){
       printf("\t%s\n",applicants[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<apps-1;i++){
        c=strcmp(applicants[i],applicants[i+1]);
        printf("\n%d\n",c);
        if(c>0)
            strcpy(temp,applicants[i]);
            strcpy(applicants[i],applicants[i+1]);
            strcpy(applicants[i+1],temp);
    }

    printf("\n\n alphebatize order\n");
    printf("-------------------\n");
    for (i=0;i<apps;i++){
       printf("\t%s\n",applicants[i]);
    }


if(strcmp(applicants[0],applicants[1])>0){
        printf("\n\n%s is greater than %s",applicants[0],applicants[1]);
    }


}
```

Comment: Don't write the code so tight, it's hard for humans to read code without white spaces, you can use them to make it easier to read, the compiler will ignore them anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement lacks braces here

```
if(c>0)
    strcpy(temp,applicants[i]);
    strcpy(applicants[i],applicants[i+1]);
    strcpy(applicants[i+1],temp);
```

this means the same as

```
if (c > 0)
 {
    strcpy(temp, applicants[i]);
 }
strcpy(applicants[i], applicants[i + 1]);
strcpy(applicants[i + 1], temp);
```

so you are overwriting `applicants[i]` with `applicants[i + 1]` and then writing to `applicants[i + 1]` the **previous** value that was stored in `temp`, which is not necessarily `applicants[i]`.

You need to add braces

```
if (c > 0)
 {
    strcpy(temp, applicants[i]);
    strcpy(applicants[i], applicants[i + 1]);
    strcpy(applicants[i + 1], temp);
 }
```

Comment: yea i was playing around with the code a bit i must of deleted them, fixed it, okay thanks i just fixed it. added another loop within and the program ran smoothly. Thanks